# Apply multiple filters, but not cascading (the following one over the preceding one in the filters array)

Tags: apache-flex, filter, effects, dropshadow

i've searched a lot but with no success, it seems no one has ever had this problem.
I have a `displayObject`, i want to apply (for example) two filters on it: let say two `dropShadowFilter`, one with `inner=true`, and the other with `inner=false`.
As stated in the documentation, filters are applied in the order they appear in the `filters` array. So, if you put the outer shadow filter first, then the second filter will be applied to the generated shadow too.
Changing the order is not a exhaustive solution, the problem remains, and applying different filters the weird effect can be reproduced again.

I'm looking for a way to avoid this, that is to **have filters applied all to the original object, not modified by any other filter**.

Many thanks.

Below a fragment of code useful to make some quick test.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:DropShadowFilter id="dropShadowOuter"
                            inner="false"
                            distance="65"
                            color="#000000"
                            alpha="0.4"/>
        <s:DropShadowFilter id="dropShadowInner"
                            inner="true"
                            distance="9"
                            color="#f3f951"
                            alpha="1"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.UIComponent;

            protected function applyFilters_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                (OutIn.textDisplay as UIComponent).filters = [dropShadowOuter,dropShadowInner];
                (InOut.textDisplay as UIComponent).filters = [dropShadowInner,dropShadowOuter];
                (Out.textDisplay as UIComponent).filters = [dropShadowInner];
                (In.textDisplay as UIComponent).filters = [dropShadowOuter];
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Button id="applyFilters" label="apply filters" click="applyFilters_clickHandler(event)"/>

    <s:TextArea id="OutIn" 
        text="EXAMPLE TEXT"
                width="600" height="200"
                fontFamily="Arial Black"
                fontSize="72"/>

        <s:TextArea id="InOut" text="EXAMPLE TEXT"
                width="600" height="200"
                fontFamily="Arial Black"
                fontSize="72"/>

        <s:TextArea  id="Out"
                     text="EXAMPLE TEXT"
                    width="600" height="200"
                    fontFamily="Arial Black"
                    fontSize="72"/>

        <s:TextArea  id="In"
                     text="EXAMPLE TEXT"
                    width="600" height="200"
                    fontFamily="Arial Black"
                    fontSize="72"/>



    </s:VGroup>


</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying filters happens on the current bitmapdata that you apply the filter on. So its not possible to find your solution with one TextArea and multiple filters.
You could try to use multiple TextArea's and one filter on each TextArea and overlap those textarea's with a nice blendmode.

```
<s:Group blendMode="multiply">

        <s:TextArea  id="Out"
                     alpha=".5"
                     filters="{[dropShadowOuter]}"
                     text="EXAMPLE TEXT"
                     width="600" height="200"
                     fontFamily="Arial Black"
                     fontSize="72"/>
        <s:TextArea  id="In"
                     alpha=".5"
                     filters="{[dropShadowInner]}"
                     text="EXAMPLE TEXT" 
                     width="600" height="200"
                     fontFamily="Arial Black"
                     fontSize="72"/>
    </s:Group>
```

This example above isn't your solution but might give you a step in the right direction.